# How to properly make a Fetch request using Selenium

Tags: javascript, python, selenium-webdriver, fetch

I need to make a specific http reqest (GET or POST) which has custom HTTP headers with Selenium using Python and get response JSON into Python back. Browser should go through the proxy server.

The most accurate way I found is to make a properly formed JS fetch request.

I have tried the following:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options


proxy_server_url = "127.0.0.1:8888"
chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
chrome_options.add_argument('--proxy-server=%s' % proxy_server_url)
chrome_options.add_argument("ignore-certificate-errors")

chrome = webdriver.Chrome(options=chrome_options)

chrome.get("https://myhttpheader.com/")

print(chrome.execute_script("fetch('https://myhttpheader.com/', {headers: {'Accept': '*/*','Accept-Language': 'ru,en-US;q=0.9,en;q=0.8,ru-RU;q=0.7','Cache-Control': 'no-cache','Connection': 'keep-alive','Origin': 'https://myhttpheader.com','Pragma': 'no-cache','Referer': 'https://myhttpheader.com/','Sec-Fetch-Dest': 'empty','Sec-Fetch-Mode': 'cors','Sec-Fetch-Site': 'cross-site','CUSTOM_HEADER_1': 'value_1','CUSTOM_HEADER_2': 'value_2' }})"))

chrome.quit()
```

There is several problems:

1. such fetch request returns Promise. I can manually view returned data in console by `fetch(...).then(response=>response.json()).then(data=>{ console.log(data); })`, but how can I access it in python through selenium?
2. I do not see any requests at the proxy server, thus it ignores proxy setup. What is wrong at the proxy setup?

Answer (score 1):

Fetch is async so use execute_async_script :

```
html = driver.execute_async_script('''
  let callback = arguments[0]
  fetch("https://somwurl", {
    headers: { /* headers go here */ }.
    method: "GET", // or POST
    body: "" //  for POST only
  }).then(r => r.text()).then(callback)
''')
```